# database connection error on Pycharm Windows

Tags: windows, sqlite, pycharm, windows-firewall

i'm tryng to create a sqlite database in my flask project in PyCharm, but i'm getting this error 
[image: access denied while opening database]

I think its a windows firewall issue but i don´t know how to resolve it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED: I deleted the Pycharm rule in windows firewall, and the pop up appear, i allow it and works !